# Hide Trustpilot widget with PHP if no reviews exist

Tags: php, trustpilot

I am trying to find a way to hide the space of the trustpilot-widget if no reviews exist for the spesific product (id). Either with php or javascript or jquery. Maybe anyone have done something similar?

I have tried to read and filter the contene with php and curl, but calling the url to trustpilot iframe url just gives me the same content either there are reviews or not.

Comment: Requesting the widget URL is hardly going to do the job; you would have to check whether they have an API you can use to query the reviews for a specific product.

Comment: Hi @neppers have you fine solution ?

Comment: No, I did not solve it..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have already managed to resolve the issue. Here's something I found on their forum/support.

Apparently you can pass on the attribute

```
data-no-reviews="collapse"
```

to hide the empty spaces if the Trustpilot product has no review.

This solution didn't fully resolve the issue I was having, as the above attribute will collapse the widget section but doesn't render default no review message or custom no review message, hopefully it will resolve your issue.

Here's the link to the above attribute

https://support.trustpilot.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/11186232962066-How-to-Hide-Trustpilot-widget-in-React-if-there-are-no-reviews-exist